# access object key and value in *ngFor angular8

Tags: angular, object, angular6, angular8, ngfor

I want to access object key and value in ngFor
for example this is my array

```
var array = [
  {'random1':value1},
  {'random2':value2},
  {'random3': value3}
]
```

now the object keys are all dynamic and i use my array like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of arrayl; let i of index">
  <td>{{i+1}}</td>
  <td>item.key</td>// here i want object key
  <td>item.value</td>// here object value
</tr>
```

another question
if my array look like this

```
var array2 = [
 ['random1',value1],
 ['random2',value2],
 ['random3',value3]
]
```

then how can in acheive same thing

thanks in advance

Comment: first array is object of array and second array is array of array. then how can you achieve same thing? what is your ultimate goal please describe

Comment: i mean in my *ngFor i want item.key = array[item][0]//first value, and for item.value = array[item][1]//second value @Abu Sufian

Answer (score 4):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwkcva)
case 1

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
   <td>{{i+1}}</td>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let el of item | keyvalue">
       <td>{{el.key}}</td>
       <td>{{el.value}}</td>
   </ng-container>
</tr>
```

case 2

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of array2; let i = index">
   <td>{{i+1}}</td>
   <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
   <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Be aware of using impure pipes. This will not work if the array items change.

Comment: thanks @pc_coder now i don't have to change my array, its working

Comment: Hello @pc_coder , how can i acheive same thing in angular mat-table

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit strange but you can do something like this:

**First case:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of array; index as i">
  <td>{{i+1}}</td>
  <td>{{ getKey(item) }}</td>
  <td>{{ item[getKey(item)] }}</td>
</tr>

// on component class
getKey(item: any): string {
  return Object.keys(item)[0];
}
```

**Second case:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of array2; index as i">
  <td>{{i+1}}</td>
  <td>{{ item[0] }}</td>
  <td>{{ item[1] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: function is not good way . It always listen that is bad for performance !

Comment: @Danilo Torchio have you tried the second case because for me its not working

Comment: Yeah, I don't like the first case either. Look this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jx99zz). Both samples is working correctly. @pc_coder you do not have to put de index (i) because each item is a value of the first array.

Comment: thank you @DaniloTorchio now its working, and is there any big problem in first case because i have to change my array if it is?

Comment: As @pc_coder comments, using the first approach is not a good idea thinking about performance but it should work in any case.